# Insert mode function/abbreviation/snippet in vim

Tags: vim, elixir, vi

In `elixir` we need to write a lot of maps(key-value pairs).

Syntax is:

```
%{one: one, two: two, three: three}
```

How can we write some kind of function/snippet/abbreviation so that we can achieve:

```
${1:one}: ${1:one} # => %{one: one_} # => where _ denotes cursor
```

Where we enter `one` and it does the following:

1. Enters one in `key: value` pair, i.e. `one: one`
2. Takes cursor to second `one`'s end character i.e. `one: one(cursor)`

And if we have to use some snippet for this then how can we assign some `shortcut-key` to it ?

========================

## Example:

========================

Say I'm anywhere in a file (mostly inside `%{}` for elixir)
I hit some keyboard shortcut (e.g. ) and type `elephant` then i want to get the following:

`elephant: elephant` and want my cursor at the end of second word's last letter(i.e. t).

1. Initially `%{|}` where `|` denotes cursor.
2. We press: `<C-m>` and get `%{term|: term}`. and `term` - first word is selected.
3. We write: `elephant` and get `%{elephant: elephant|}`
4. Done.

Comment: I don't understand what effect do you want... those `$ # % ...` in your code block confused me too.

Comment: Do you want to type "one" and get "%{one: one}" with cursor before closing bracket?

Comment: If so you can use UltiSnips or Snipmate plugin, which already has many snippets and easy to create your own. If plugins are undesirable, you can use simple macro or mapping. Please let us know what exactly you want. =)

Comment: Oh...I want to press some keyboard-shortcut and want: 

`things_i_type: same_thing_i_type_` and cursor at underscore.

Where ☝ same_thing_i_type will get written automatically. And I need to do this with some kind of key-trigger (e.g. <C-m>)


Real Case: 
I'm inside `%{}` and hit `<C-m>` and type: stackoverflow then I'll get `%{stackoverflow: stackoverflow}` and my cursor will be at the last letter(w) of second stackoverflow.

Comment: I've added the example in the question description.